# Microsoft Azure IOT Hub and custom routes

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm adding custom routes to my Azure IOT hub resource. I've added blob storage as an end point and added  that to a route. I want to add service bus queue as another route. I've created service bus and service bus queue and created an end point for that. But I can not able to add that endpoint to my new route(It should have auto-populated to endpoint field and also the created endpoint is not listing). I'm using Azure free trial subscription

Comment: Free should have 5 routes. When you say you created an endpoint, you mean created the endpoint in the IoT Hub, but it is not listing the routes section?

Comment: yes, I've created the end point for the service bus queue but in the add route window under the endpoint drop down field, the created endpoint is not listing.

Comment: @DanielIssac What is your Azure IoT Hub scale tier? In the case of **F1 - Free**, you can add only one custom endpoint.

Comment: @RomanKiss Thanks. I'm using IoT hub **F1-Free**  tier. As you said, we can create only one custom endpoint in free tier :(